# Modifying the order of reading CSV Files in Python according to the name

Tags: python, csv, rename, filenames, file-rename

I have 1000 CSV files with names `Radius_x` where `x` stands for `0,1,2...11,12,13...999`. But when I read the files and try to analyse the results, I wish to read them in the same order of whole numbers as listed above. But the code reads as follows (for example): `....145,146,147,148,149,15,150,150...159,16,160,161,......` and so on.

I know that if we rename the CSV files as `Radius_xyz` where `xyz = 000,001,002,003,....010,011,012.....999`, the problem could be resolved. Kindly help me as to how I can proceed.

Comment: To improve the quality of your question and to make the problem reproducible please provide a minimum working example of your code.

Comment: can you share your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort a list of paths numerically in python, first find all the files you are looking to open, then sort that iterable with a key which extracts the number.

With [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

files = list(Path("/tmp/so/").glob("Radius_*.csv"))  # Path.glob returns a generator which needs to be put in a list

files.sort(key=lambda p: int(p.stem[7:]))  # `Radius_` length is 7
```

`files` contains

```py
[PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_1.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_2.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_3.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_4.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_5.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_6.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_7.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_8.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_9.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_10.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_11.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_12.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_13.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_14.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_15.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_16.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_17.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_18.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_19.csv'),
 PosixPath('/tmp/so/Radius_20.csv')]
```

**NB.** `files` is a list of paths not strings, but most functions which deal with files accept both types.

A similar approach could be done with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), which would give a list of strings not paths.